# How to re-use a branch of commits periodically?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have code base in which I need to reuse a branch full of changes at a later time.  This code is for testing, and will not be merged into the main codebase, but I would like to maintain the provenance of the branch if possible.

For example, let's say I have this

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
     \            
      1-2-3
```

I want to do this.

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
     \           \
      1-2-3       1-2-3
```

I can cherry-pick 1, 2, and 3 onto i, but I am hoping there is an easier and more traceable way to do this.

Do I `git pull --rebase` the 1st 1-2-3 branch?

Comment: As a code reviewer, I would be suspicious of tests that only apply to a branch other than the actual code headed for production. Perhaps you need to refactor your code to make it more testable?

Comment: Keep rebasing on top of the branch. That’s it.

Comment: @chepner This code is a hardware test branch.  It turns off certain hardware features (the main purpose of the device) and is a released code for a specific set of tests.  I suppose that we could ifdef the various sections to enable the special build.  Perhaps we will add a task to do this in the future.  You do make a good point though.  bifurcating the code like this makes this problem arise every time we need to test.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
     \           \
      1-2-3       1-2-3
```

But you can easily have

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
     \           \
      1-2-3       1'-2'-3'
```

(A commit can only exist once. If you rebase or cherry-pick, you create *new* commits.)

The following command will work in your local repository:

```
git rebase i branch-which-points-to-3
```

It takes all commits reachable from `branch-which-points-to-3` , but not reachable from `i` (i.e. commits `1..3`) and re-applies them as new commits on top of `i`. The original commits `1..3` are no longer reachable and the new commits will have new commit ids (commit hashes). You can no longer do a simple fast-forward push of this branch, but would need to do a force-push since you are effectively rewriting history.

If you want your old commits to still be reachable, create a new branch pointing to your old commit(s) *before* rebasing. This will keep them reachable through this branch name. You can either rebase the old or the newly created branch, depending on your requirements.

Note that this is not all that different from cherry-picking: `git cherry-pick 1..3` will create copies of the commits too. I like to think of cherry-picking as the inverse of rebasing (source and destination are swapped) – with rebasing I tell Git *where to* I want to rebase, whereas with cherry-picking I tell Git *where from* I want to pick.

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants. The original commits must remain reachable.

Comment: It isn't? But if they need to remain reachable, creating a new branch before rebase will keep them reachable

Comment: Agreed, so this needs to be included in the answer, that's all I'm saying. It's trivially obvious to you and me, but then the whole answer is trivially obvious to you and me; to help the OP we need to say everything the OP needs to know.

Comment: Ranged cherry-pick sounds more straightforward to me. It also has the benefit of keeping the old commits reachable without an extra command to create a branch.

Comment: @jingx you still need to create the extra branch for cherry-picking, otherwise you would be modifying an existing branch (e.g. `main`).

Comment: @knittl yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

> more traceable

The way Git traces provenance is with ancestry. Ancestry is literally provenance here, the normal-usage distinctions simply don't exist in Git's world.

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i    mainline
     \             
      1-2-3          instrumented-base
```

The way to merge the subsequent mainline changes is to merge them:

```
git checkout -b this-test-today instrumented-base
git merge mainline
```

producing

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i    mainline
     \           \
      \     ,---- T    this-test-today       
       1-2-3         instrumented-base
```

and now your this-test-today tip records its provenance.